# <canvas>に動画をプレビュー表示したい

Tags: javascript, html

event.target.filesでよみとったファイルを
`<canvas>`に表示したいです。

どなたか、やり方を教えていただけませんか？

Answer (score 4):

まず、`URL.createObjectURL(file)`でファイルのBlobURLを得て、用意しておいたVideo要素のsrc属性に指定します。
次にビデオを再生しながら`ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0)`をすれば、その瞬間のフレームがCanvasに描画されるので、それを`requestAnimationFrame`を使い連続的に行えばできます。